# Determinant of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -2a &a+b &a+c \\ b+a& -2b &b+c \\ c+a&c+b & -2c \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

Evaluate $$D=\begin{vmatrix}
-2a &a+b  &a+c \\ 
 b+a& -2b &b+c \\ 
 c+a&c+b  & -2c
\end{vmatrix}$$

My try:

Applying $R_1 \to R_1+R_2$ we get

$$D=\begin{vmatrix}
b-a&a-b  &a+b+2c \\ 
 b+a& -2b &b+c \\ 
 c+a&c+b  & -2c
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now apply $$C_1 \to C_1+C_2$$

$$D=\begin{vmatrix}
0&a-b  &a+b+2c \\ 
 a-b& -2b &b+c \\ 
 2c+a+b&c+b  & -2c
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now apply $C_2 \to C_2 +C_3$

$$D= \begin{vmatrix}
0&2a+2c  &a+b+2c \\ 
 a-b& c-b &b+c \\ 
 2c+a+b&b-c  & -2c
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now use $R_3 \to R_3+R_2$

$$D= \begin{vmatrix}
0&2a+2c  &a+b+2c \\ 
 a-b& c-b &b+c \\ 
 2c+2a&0  & b-c
\end{vmatrix}$$

any way to proceed here using elementary operations?

Comment: Why not use the standard formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Comment: Yes... using the standard approach is easy, though it gives a tedious solution

Comment: You will do better subtracting rows/columns.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(a,b,c) $ be the determinant. Note that each term of $p$ has degree 3 (sum of degrees of $a,b,c$).

Note that $p(a,-a,c) = 0$, hence $a+b$ divides $p$.

Similarly we see that $a+c, b+c$ divide $p$.

Hence $p$ has the form $p(a,b,c) = k (a+b)(b+c)(a+c)$ for some constant $k$.

Compute the determinant for $a=b=c={1\over 2}$ to get $k = 4$.

Comment: For a simple proof of the factoring statement see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4158465/27978.