# Application of remainder theorem and factor theorems to multivariable polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

The remainder theorem and factor theorem are usually stated as follows:

**The Remainder Theorem**

> When a polynomial p(x) is divided by x − c, the remainder is equal to the value of
> p(c).

**The Factor Theorem**

> The term x − c is a factor of a polynomial p(x) if and only if p(c)=0.

Now I am skeptic that whether these theorems are applicable on any polynomial of degree greater than or equal to 1 i.e to multi-variable polynomial  or these theorems are applicable only for single-variable polynomials because these theorems are stated for a polynomial p(x) which in my opinion refers to a single-variable polynomial.

This question came to me by the following question which I recently encountered :

> Using factor theorem, show that $a - b, b-c,$ and $c-a$ are the factors of $$a(b^2-c^2) + b(c^2-a^2) + c (a^2-b^2).$$

In the above question if we try to put $a = b$, or $b = c$, or $c=a$ we will see that the value of polynomial becomes zero. It gives us some feeling that $a - b, b-c$ and $c-a$ are the factors of the given polynomial but is it correct.

**Can we apply factor theorem to multivariable polynomials ?**

Comment: There is no need to involve multivariate polynomials here. Look at the expression as a quadratic in $a$, which has the roots $b,c$, then it factors as $\dots$

Comment: @dxiv then how can you account for the factor b-c

Comment: $...$ factors as $k(a-b)(a-c)$ where $k$ is the leading coefficient, in this case $c-b$. Or, directly by symmetry in $a,b,c$ (assuming you have a typo in the post and that's supposed to be $a(b^2\color{red}{-}c^2)$).

Comment: @dxiv I am unable to comprehend, please elaborate

Comment: In general, if you have a quadratic $k x^2 + m x + n$ and you know it has the roots $x=p,x=q$ then you know it factors as $k(x-p)(x-q)$. Here, you have the quadratic $(c-b)\,a^2 + (b^2-c^2) a -b^2c+bc^2$ which you know has the roots $a=b,a=c$, so it factors as $(c-b)(a-b)(a-c)$.

Answer (score 7):

The Factor Theorem does not directly carry over to multivariate polynomials. More context and a proof of the *[Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) for principal ideals* are provided in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222657) to [Does there exist a formal statement of the Multivariable Factor Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222592/does-there-exist-a-formal-statement-of-the-multivariable-factor-theorem).

For the purpose of OP's example, however, the following simpler theorem suffices, which can be proved with entirely elementary means.

> If $P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1},x_n)$ and $f(x_1, x_2,\dots,x_{n-1})$ are polynomials that satisfy $$P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1},f(x_1, x_2,\dots,x_{n-1})) \equiv 0$$ then $P$ has $x_n - f$ as a factor i.e. there exists a polynomial $Q(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ such that $$P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1},x_n) = \left(x_n - f(x_1, x_2,\dots,x_{n-1})\right) \cdot Q(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$$

Writing the polynomial as a sum of monomials $\;P(x_1, x_2, \dots,x_n) = \sum_{k_j} c_{k_1k_2\dots k_n}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\dots x_n^{k_n}\;$ and using the identity $\;a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\dots+b^{k-1})\;$:

$$
\begin{align}
P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) &= P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n) - P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}))
\\ &= \sum_{k_j} c_{k_1k_2\dots k_n}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\dots x_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}\left( x_n^{k_n}-\left(f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1})\right)^{k_n}\right)
\\ &= \left( x_n-f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1})\right) \cdot \sum_{k_j} c_{k_1k_2\dots k_n}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\dots x_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}\left( x_n^{k_n-1}+ \dots\right)
\\ &= \left( x_n-f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1})\right) \cdot Q(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)
\end{align}
$$

Using this result for $P(a,b,c) = a(b^2-c^2) + b(c^2-a^2) + c (a^2-b^2)$ and $f(a,b)=a$, it is easily verified that $P(a,b,f(a,b)) \equiv 0$, so $P(a,b,c)$ has a factor of $c-f(a,b)=c-a\,$. Since $P$ has [cyclic symmetry](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cyclic-polynomials/), it must also have $a-b$ and $b-c$ as factors, so in the end $P(a,b,c) = \lambda (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ where $\lambda$ must be a constant for $P$ to have degree $\deg P = 3$, and the constant can be determined by comparing the coefficients of any of the monomials, which gives $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: How $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n) - P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}))$

Comment: @user933496 $P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1},f(x_1, x_2,\dots,x_{n-1})) = 0$ so the second term is zero.

Comment: How does that become $ P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{k_j} c_{k_1k_2\dots k_n}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\dots x_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}\left( x_n^{k_n}-\left(f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1})\right)^{k_n}\right)
$.

Comment: @user933496 Just subtract: $$P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n)=\sum_{k_j} c_{k_1k_2\dots k_n}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\dots x_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}x_n^{k_n} \\ 0 = P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}))=\sum_{k_j} c_{k_1k_2\dots k_n}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\dots x_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}\left(f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1})\right)^{k_n}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can apply factor theorem to multivariable polynomials as follows-

Here you have a multivariable polynomial

$P(a,b,c)=a(b^2-c^2) + b(c^2-a^2) + c (a^2-b^2)$

Now if you find some polynomial $g(b,c)$ such that

$P(g(b,c),b,c)=0$ for all values of $b$ and $c$, then you may say that $(a-g(b,c))$ is a factor of above polynomial.

This is factor theorem for polynomials you are interested in.

For example, Here you found a polynomial $g(b,c)=b+0.c$. which when replaced by $a$ in original polynomial. then it evaluated to $0$, irrespective of what $b,c$ are, Hence $a-(g(b,c))=a-b$ is a factor of above polynomial.

Now suppose you divide this polynomial by some $a-g(b,c)=a-(b+c)$ where $g(b,c)=b+c$, then the remainder you will get will be $P(g(b,c),b,c)=-b^2c+c^2b$ which you can check by long division (as polynomials in a).

also when we had a single variable polynomial we wrote as

$P(x)= d(x).Q(x)+R(x)$. Here you can write

$P(a,b,c)=(a-g(b,c)).(a(c-b)+c^2b-b^2c$ where our divisor was $d(a,b,c)=a-g(b,c)$, quotient which we obtained by long division was $Q(a,b,c)=a(c-b)$ and remainder as
$R(a,b,c)=0.a-b^2c+c^2b$

In nutshell you can treat multivariate polynomials as single-variable polynomials only as @dxiv explained in his comments

Comment: "*we obtained by long division*" — You have to be careful there, because there is no long division between arbitrary multivariate polynomials. It happens to work here because $d(a,b,c)$ is a *monic* polynomial, but that's not the case in general.

Comment: The statement was used to make the questioner relate with multivariable polynomials

Comment: However you can divide by converting the given polynomial to  a quadratic in $a$

Comment: Right, and it works the same way for higher degrees with $d(a,b,c) = a-g(b,c)$ which is monic in $a$. It's just that calling it long division can invite some confusion in the multivariate case.

Comment: So what better term can I use

Comment: You could maybe call it "*long division (as polynomials in $a$)*" to clarify, or add a reference to [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116029/why-polynomial-division-algorithm-works-for-x-a-or-any-monic-polynomial) or [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767332/a-question-about-the-division-algorithm-of-polynomials) which explain why it works in this case.

Comment: @dxiv thankyou sir providing correction

Comment: @LalitTolani Can you give some proof for your statements ? Like the one that we encounter while studying Remainder Theorem in High school.

Comment: For which statement you want proof

Comment: Suppose root of d(x) is c then P(c)= R(c). Similarly if root of d(a,b,c) is a=g(b,c), then P(g(b,c),b,c)=R(g(b,c),b,c)