# Polynomial that forces a polynomial to be $0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Suppose that $f(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb C[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ is a polynomial. Then what are the conditions that $f$ must satisfy (preferably necessary and sufficient) such that there exists a $g\in \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ for which $f(g(x_1,\dots,x_n),x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a polynomial identical to $0$?

I am sure that there is a theory based on this question, if someone could point me to the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is $\Bbb{C}[\cdots]$?

Comment: @FShrike This is the standard notation for the set of all polynomial with $n+1$ indeterminates with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This just means $f$ Isa multiple of $x_0-g(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$.

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [Application of remainder theorem and factor theorems to multivariable polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155545/application-of-remainder-theorem-and-factor-theorems-to-multivariable-polynomial/).

Comment: @dxiv: Oh wonderful! This is not only related, its more or less the answer. Two questions though: 

1. Is there a proper reference that discusses this?
2. Is there a generalization of this e.g. $f(g_1,g_2,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ (or with more $g_i$) is identical to zero? I suspect this is not possible as one is behind the scenes using factorization in one variable.

Comment: There is no such direct generalization. Consider for example the irreducible polynomial $\,f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1-x_2+x_3\,$, then $\,f\left(g(x_3), g(x_3)+x_3, x_3\right) \equiv 0\,$ for any $\,g\,$.