# What is the remainder when dividing the polynomial $f(x,y)$ by $(x-y)$?

Tags: polynomials

Remainder factor theorem states that if the polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-c)$ then the remainder is $f(c)$, how does this work for multivariable polynomials?

I am confused by this:
[image]

How does showing $f(x,x)=0$ prove $(x-y)$ divides $f(x,y)$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: See for example my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155545/application-of-remainder-theorem-and-factor-theorems-to-multivariable-polynomial/4158465#4158465), yours is the case $n=2,x_1=x,x_2=y,f(x_1)=x_2$. Basically, you show that $(y-x) \mid f(x,y) - f(x,x)$ for any bivariate polynomial $f(x,y)$, then if $f(x,x) = 0 \ldots$